# setAttribute for created element

Tags: javascript, createelement, setattribute

I have already 3 paragraphs and need to create the 4th one using JavaScript
It's created successfully.

```
const new_h2 = document.createElement('h2')
```

and assigns an ID to the h2

```
new_h2.setAttribute('id', 'heading4');
```

now I get that h2 with its ID

```
const heading4 = document.getElementById('heading4')
```

The problem appears when I try to use it in an If statement

```
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        console.log(window.scrollY);
        if(window.scrollY >= 400 && window.scrollY < 800){
            heading1.style.color = '#cc1'
            // console.log('section1 is styled');
        }else if(window.scrollY >= 800 && window.scrollY < 1200){
            heading2.style.color = '#cc1'
            // console.log('section2 is styled');
        }else if(window.scrollY >= 1200 && window.scrollY < 1600){
            heading3.style.color = '#cc1'
            // console.log('section3 is styled');
        }else if(window.scrollY >= 1600){
            heading4.style.color = '#cc1'
            // console.log('section4 is styled');
        }else{
            heading1.style.color = '#fff'
            heading2.style.color = '#fff'
            heading3.style.color = '#fff'
            heading4.style.color = '#fff'
        }
})
```

The log shows the following error:
`Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')`
and I guess that comes from heading4.style.color
but I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Creating an element doesn’t automatically put it in the document. Why not simply use `new_h2`? You already have the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you never add `new_h2` to the page. Since it's not in the page's DOM, `getElementById("heading4")` returns `null` — there's no element in the DOM with that `id`:

```js
const new_h2 = document.createElement("h2");

new_h2.setAttribute("id", "heading4");

console.log(document.getElementById("heading4")); // null

// Add the element to the page's DOM
document.body.appendChild(new_h2);

console.log(document.getElementById("heading4")); // finds it
```

You need to add the element to the DOM in order to find it in the DOM with methods like `getElementById` or `querySelector`.

But note that you *already* have a reference to the element (`new_h2`). There's no need to look it up, and probably no need for it to have an `id`. Just use `new_h2`. (You probably still have to add it to the page though.)

---

Side note: You don't need to use `setAttribute` to set an element's `id`, you can use the *reflected property* for it:

```
new_h2.id = "heading4";
```

Most (but not all) useful attributes have reflected properties. You can see which ones do [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) or [in the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#htmlelement).

Comment: I think ```new_div.appendChild(h2)``` should add it to the DOM

Comment: @HanyTaha - It does. That isn't in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the `new_h2` you created via JavaScript into the DOM before doing calling `document.getElementById('heading4')`:

```js
const new_h2 = document.createElement('h2')
new_h2.setAttribute('id', 'heading4')

// Added it to the DOM
document.body.appendChild(new_h2)
// Then you can query it
const heading4 = document.getElementById('heading4')
```